# Resize image from command line to 1024x576

Tags: command-line, 18.04, ubuntu-mate, image-processing

I need to convert images down to 1024x576 using the command line.

I have Gimp, VLC, and Inkscape, on Ubuntu MATE 18.04.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Imagemagick can do it. Install it with:

`sudo apt install imagemagick`

Resizing can be done like this:

```
convert -resize 1024x576 input.png output.png
```